# watch in visual studio 2015 keeps giving me this error: identifier "_fictionBook" is undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
   //main.cpp
#include "Fiction.h"

using namespace std; 

int main()
{


    int choice =-1; 

    while (choice != 0)
    {
        displayMenu();
        cin >> choice; 
        cin.ignore(); 
        switch (choice)
        {
    //case 1-3 exclude for not having anything in them yet.

        case 4: system("cls"); //add a book         this has to come first
            {   cout << "Enter the title of the book" << endl;
            string userChoice;
            getline(cin, userChoice);
            Fiction().addBook(userChoice); 
            }
        default: cout << "thats not a choice" << endl; 

        }
    }





    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}




//Fiction.h
#pragma once
#include<string>
#include<vector>

class Fiction
{
private: 
    std::vector<std::string> _fictionBook;

public:


    Fiction();
    ~Fiction();
    void addBook(std::string title);
};



//Fiction.cpp
#include "Fiction.h"



Fiction::Fiction()
{

}

Fiction::~Fiction()
{
}

void Fiction::addBook(std::string title)
{
    _fictionBook.push_back(title); 
}
```

The issue i'm having is that I can not push back anything into _fictionBook. This does not stop the code from running, the watch tab in visual studios is where it is telling me that   identifier "_fictionBook" is undefined. i've spent a great deal of time looking for an answer but I can't seem to find it. Any help I could get would be greatly appreciated.

Update: Just checked I am not debugging in "release mode"

Update:_fictionBook is not showing up in the local tab

Comment: Are you debugging in "Release" mode? This doesn't work well. And also post ba [MCVE]

Comment: you should add the a main function and how are you using this class. from the code above there should not be any problem. 
are you in debug mode ? and you should check the Locals tab to see if you can see the member there

Comment: What is `Fiction().addBook(userChoice);`?

Comment: Fiction().addBook(userChoice); should push_back userChoice into _fictionBook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem that I see is that you do not call your `addBook(string)` on a `Fiction` object. You never declare a `Fiction` object on which to apply operations... You call it on a `Fiction()`? You shouldn't do operations on variables that don't exist (and this variable doesn't exist, it doesn't even have a name).

If you try the following `main.cpp`, it declares a `Fiction` object and adds a book to it without problem :

```
//main.cpp
#include "Fiction.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string userChoice("Kill six billion demons, by Abbadon");
    Fiction myBooksOfFiction;
    myBooksOfFiction.addBook(userChoice);
    return 0;
}
```

The reason why Visual Studio tells you that the identifier `_fictionBook` is undefined, is because there is no such identifier. `_fictionBook` is a data member of the class `Fiction`. You have to declare a `Fiction` object and access the data member through that object.

Note also that the code you provided is calling functions you've not provided (`displayMenu()`, for one) but which doesn't seem relevant to your question. This should be in a comment of your question, I guess, but I felt important to write here that your code as provided doesn't build at least in part because of that.